# Нужно вместо букв подстовлять определённые знаки

Tags: python

Задача вот в чём: Я ввожу текст на русском, а программа мне заменяет определённые буквы определёнными знаками, при этом все знаки препинания остаются на своих местах.

Пример работы: я ввожу "привет", мне программа выдаёт `G{}<>)(><$`  где "п" заменяется на "G", и так далее.

Если надо, могу оставить весь массив со знаками.

Comment: Чтобы решить эту задачу, нужно знать, что такое словарь (dictionary) и цикл for.

Answer (score 2):

создайте словарь и заменяйте:

```
_dict = {
    'п': 'G', 
    'р': '{}',
    'и': '<>',
    'в': ')(',
    'е': '><',
    'т': '$',
}

text = input('Введите слово: привет\n')

new_text = ''.join([_dict[s] for s in text])
print(new_text)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Замена помощью методов `translate` и `maketrans` (см. [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)):

```
d = {
    'п': 'G', 
    'р': '{}',
    'и': '<>',
    'в': ')(',
    'е': '><',
    'т': '$',
}

text = input()
print(text.translate(str.maketrans(d)))
```